# How can I use javafx in visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I want to javafx in vs code
as for versions I am using jdk-16.0.2.7-hotspot
How can I use javafx in my projects?
Is it possible?

Comment: For your information, [Zulu JDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk) includes JavaFX. Also, maybe you should consider upgrading to JDK 17 as this is a LTS (long term service) version meaning that it will be supported for a few years.

Comment: See the [openjfx docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) that detail how to get started using JavaFX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, ensure that you're using the latest version of VSCode. Then, click on Settings (Gear icon at the bottom left), click on extensions, type JavaFX, Install JavaFX Support and FXML viewer. Then, install JavaFX library. ([Link](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)). Create a new project, in the explorer tab, in java projects, click on Plus sign in referenced libraries. Point it towards your installation directory of JavaFX SDK.

Add this to VM Option,

--module-path /path/to/JavaFX/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls

(make sure to paste path to javafx lib folder after --module-path)

Make sure you have your runtime defined in VSCode, and it should be done :)