# A JNI error + JavaFX error, matching java and javac versions along with matching JDK, do I need to update past Java 8?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I had this code working on a previous machine but have recently migrated my projects to a new environment, and am getting a new error when trying to get my project running:

```
[slick_57@slicks-pc ~/CustInfoOutline]$  /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:44419 -cp /home/slick_57/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/User/workspaceStorage/7e2f391c1a6881bc9c3688d73bd45c15/redhat.java/jdt_ws/CustInfoOutline_e6fdbd3c/bin Driver 
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Stage
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 7 more
```

I made sure that my java and javac versions are all inline with my IDEs selected runtime:

```
{
"java.configuration.runtimes": [

{
    "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
    "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk",
    "default": true
},
{
    "name": "JavaSE-11",
    "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk",
},
]
}
```

Any input is appreciated, this project previously ran on a newer version of Java so I think this may have something more to do with that than runtime errors?

Comment: It's strange the missing class is named `Stage` and not `javafx.stage.Stage`. You don't happen to have your own `Stage` class (in the unnamed package), do you?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Oracle JDK 8 instead of Open JDK, it will probably work.

Oracle JDK 8 includes JavaFX, most OpenJDK distributions do not.

Or, if you want to switch to a modern runtime, follow the instructions at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Comment: so it looks as though this took away the JavaFX errors, yet now for some reaosn when I go to run the code I get: `/usr/bin/env: ‘/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_361/bin/java’: No such file or directory` even though thats where I have the Oracle JDK installed and pointed to in IDE.

Comment: I am able to run java from terminal when sitting in the folder, just not within the IDE? I must be missing something in the IDE so that its not picking up the java file? Strange...

Comment: Whatever your current issues are, they are a product of your environment and how you have configured it. You will need to debug and fix those yourself. There is not much additional that can be done to assist you via sites like StackOverflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294852/how-can-i-use-javafx-in-visual-studio-code found it, thanks for the help!